# Point is not defined even though I imported graphics

Tags: python, graphics, python-3.x

So this is my class for a game called Zombie Dice.

I've imported graphics but I get this error and I have no idea why. Please explain some possibilities for me.

```
"File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    Game()
  File "C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\FinalProject3.py", line 17, in Game
    Yellow = DieViewYellow(Gamewindow, Point(95,75),20)
  File "C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\DieViewYellow.py", line 83, in __init__
    p1 = Point(x-25, y-25)
NameError: name 'Point' is not defined">
```

Here is my Die view class, which is giving me the issue even though graphics is imported

```
#Die View Yellow
from graphics import *

class DieViewYellow:

def __init__(self, win, center, value):
    """Create a view of a die, e.g.:
       d1 = GDie(myWin, Point(40,50), 20)
    creates a die centered at (40,50) having sides
    of length 20."""

    # first define some standard values
    self.win = win
    #self.background = Color # color of die face
    #self.foreground = Color2 # color of the pips

    # create a square for the face
    if value==0:
        x, y = center.getX(), center.getY()
        p1 = Point(x-25, y-25)
        p2 = Point(x+25, y+25)
        rect = Rectangle(p1,p2)
        rect.draw(win)
        rect.setFill('yellow')


    if value == 1:
        x, y = center.getX(), center.getY()
        p1 = Point(x-25, y-25)
        p2 = Point(x+25, y+25)
        rect = Rectangle(p1,p2)
        rect.draw(win)
        rect.setFill('yellow')
        self.Brain=Text(Point(95,75),'B')
        self.Brain.draw(self.win)

    elif value == 2:
        x, y = center.getX(), center.getY()
        p1 = Point(x-25, y-25)
        p2 = Point(x+25, y+25)
        rect = Rectangle(p1,p2)
        rect.draw(win)
        rect.setFill('yellow')
        self.Brain=Text(Point(95,75),'B')
        self.Brain.draw(self.win)


    elif value == 3:
        x, y = center.getX(), center.getY()
        p1 = Point(x-25, y-25)
        p2 = Point(x+25, y+25)
        rect = Rectangle(p1,p2)
        rect.draw(win)
        rect.setFill('yellow')
        self.Shotgun=Text(Point(95,75),'S')
        self.Shotgun.draw(self.win)


    elif value == 4:
        x, y = center.getX(), center.getY()
        p1 = Point(x-25, y-25)
        p2 = Point(x+25, y+25)
        rect = Rectangle(p1,p2)
        rect.draw(win)
        rect.setFill('yellow')
        self.Foot=Text(Point(95,75),'F')
        self.Foot.draw(self.win)


    elif value == 5:
        x, y = center.getX(), center.getY()
        p1 = Point(x-25, y-25)
        p2 = Point(x+25, y+25)
        rect = Rectangle(p1,p2)
        rect.draw(win)
        rect.setFill('yellow')
        self.Foot=Text(Point(95,75),'F')
        self.Foot.draw(self.win)

    else:
        x, y = center.getX(), center.getY()
        p1 = Point(x-25, y-25)
        p2 = Point(x+25, y+25)
        rect = Rectangle(p1,p2)
        rect.draw(win)
        rect.setFill('yellow')
        self.Shotgun=Text(Point(95,75),'S')
        self.Shotgun.draw(self.win)
```

Comment: Please touch up your formatting. Your code sample is obviously wrong, and the traceback should formatted either as code or a blockquote with extra newlines. [Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is available from the post editor UI.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but I think that was it.

Comment: They mean that it's really hard to read the code sample you posted, because you've just copied and pasted the code in. You need to format it in a special way to view code properly on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you sure that you've imported the actual graphics.py file correctly? If your text editor has autocomplete, does it recognize the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown all your code, but I *believe* you have something like this as your import statement:

```
import graphics
```

or

```
from module import graphics
```

You're trying to use the `Point` class:

```
p2 = Point(x+25, y+25) # This fails.
```

But Python doesn't know that `Point` lives inside the `graphics` module. You'll need to tell it that whenever you use `Point`:

```
p2 = graphics.Point(x+25, y+25) # This works fine!
```

You can import `Point` directly from `graphics` if you want to use it without the `graphics.` prefix.

```
from graphics import Point

p2 = Point(x+25, y+25) # This works fine now!
```

**Edit**

The question has been edited, so this answer is a bit redundant now. I'll leave it up though.

Comment: I edited out my import statement when I was reformatting my question, but the error is still there even with all of graphics imported

Comment: Can you post your import statement?

Comment: I thought I did, I think it keeps taking it out. I have from graphics import * at the top though

Comment: What graphics module is this that you're using? Are you sure it has a `Point` class inside it?

(You can see what a module contains by doing something like `print(dir(graphics))`)

Comment: @Matthew A quick google search indicates that this is (possibly) a custom graphics module used in a tutorial book. And it seems that it _does_ have a Point class. The author's name is John Zelle.

Comment: Hrm. I don't see a problem in the posted code then. It might be interesting to note that the code that calls `DieViewYellow` also makes use of `Point`, but doesn't seem to be raising an exception - though that may either be that `Point` exists in that file, or that `Point(95, 75)` simply hasn't been evaluated yet (I don't know what order Python handles these things).

Maybe try changing `from graphics import *` to `from graphics import Point, Rectangle` and see what it says?

There's a best answer marked here anyway, so perhaps the OP solved their problem.

Comment: AFAIK, python will only raise an error if it actually encounters the error over the course of the program. So, if you have, say, a branching if in a function somewhere which contains an undeclared variable, yet this particular branch is never encountered, python won't raise an error.